# finding shortest path given distance transform image

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, transform, distance, shortest-path

I am given a distance transform (below) and I need to write a program that finds the shortest path going from point A(140,200) to point B(725,1095) while making sure I am at least ten pixels away from any obstacle

[distance_transform_given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC0N3.png)

(the above image is the distance transform of [map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaG7Q.png))

This is what I have done so far:

1. I started off at the initial point and evaluated the grayscale intensity of every point around it. ( 8 neighboring points that is)
2. Then I moved to the point with the highest grayscale intensity of the 8 neighboring points.
3. Then I repeated this process but I get random turns and not the shortest path.

please do help me out

code of what I have done so far :

```
def find_max_neigh_location(np,img):
maxi = 0
x0=0
y0=0
for i in range(len(np)):
    if img[np[i][0]][np[i][1]][0] >maxi:
        maxi = img[np[i][0]][np[i][1]][0]
        x0 = np[i][0]
        y0 = np[i][1]
return x0,y0
```

## -----------------------------------------------------------------

```
def check_if_extremes(x,y):
    if(x==1099 and y==1174):return 1
    elif(y==1174 and x!=1099):return 2
    elif(x==1099 and y!=1174):return 3
    else:return 0
```

## --------------------------------------------------------

```
def find_highest_neighbour(img,x,y,visted_points):
val = check_if_extremes(x,y)
if val==1:
    neigh_points = [(x-1,y),(x-1,y-1),(x,y-1)]
    np = list(set(neigh_points)-set(visited_points))
    x0,y0 = find_max_neigh_location(np,img)
elif val==2:
    neigh_points = [(x-1,y),(x-1,y-1),(x,y-1),(x+1,y-1),(x+1,y)]
    np = list(set(neigh_points)-set(visited_points))
    x0,y0 = find_max_neigh_location(np,img)       
elif val==3:
    neigh_points = [(x-1,y),(x-1,y-1),(x,y-1),(x,y+1),(x-1,y+1)]
    np = list(set(neigh_points)-set(visited_points))
    x0,y0 = find_max_neigh_location(np,img)
elif val==0:
    neigh_points = [(x-1,y),(x-1,y-1),(x,y-1),(x,y+1),(x+1,y),(x+1,y+1),(x,y+1),(x-1,y+1)]
    np = list(set(neigh_points)-set(visited_points))
    x0,y0 = find_max_neigh_location(np,img)
for pt in neigh_points:
    visited_points.append(pt)
return x0,y0,visited_points
```

## ---------------------------------------------------------

```
def check_if_neighbour_is_final_pt(img,x,y):
l = [(x-1,y), (x+1,y),(x,y-1),(x,y+1),(x-1,y-1),(x+1,y+1),(x-1,y+1),(x+1,y-1)]
if (725,1095) in l:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

## --------------------------------------------------------------

```
x=140
y=200
pos=[]
count = 0
visited_points = [(x,y)]
keyword = True
while keyword:
    val = check_if_neighbour_is_final_pt(img,x,y)
    if val == True:
        keyword = False
    if val == False:
        count=count+1
        x,y,visited_points = find_highest_neighbour(img,x,y,visited_points)
        img[x][y] = [255,0,0]
cv2.imwrite("img\distance_transform_result__"+str(count)+".png",img)
```

Comment: this is not a free homework service. try to solve the problem yourself. you may ask for help on the way, but you may not ask for help befor you have even started thinking about the problem... come on.

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to be pointed out in a direction. I posted the whole question for completeness. I hope you'll look past that and help me out.

Comment: @Piglet
Let me mention what I have done so far ( though I do not know if it is the right approach):
I started off at the initial point and evaluated the grayscale intensity of every point around it. ( 8 neighboring points that is)
Then I moved to the point with the highest grayscale intensity of the 8 neighboring points.
Then I repeated this process but I get random turns and not the shortest path.
please do help me out :)

Comment: you should add the original image again. and add comments to your code. no one wants to read through something like that. would you?

Answer (score -1):

As you did not comment your code at all I won't read through your code.

I'll stick to what you described as your approach.

The fact that you start at point A and move to the brightest point A's neigbourhood shows that you don't know what distance transform does or what it is you see in your distance map... Never start coding if you don't know what you're dealing with.

Distance transform transforms a binary image into an image where each pixel's value is the minimum distance of the input image's foreground pixel to the background.

Dark pixels mean close to background (obstacles in your problem) and bright pixels are further away.

So moving to the brightest pixel nearby will only lead you away from the obstacles but never to your target point.

First restriction:
Never get closer to an obstacle than 10 pixels!

This means, every pixel that is closer to the obstacle (darker than 10) cannot be part of your path. So apply a global threshold of 10 to your distance map.

[image]

[image]

Now every white pixel can be used for your path to B.

The rest ist an optimization problem. There is plenty of literature on shortest path algorithms online. I'll leave that up to you...